# Unable to connect google compute engine, getting permission denied error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have accidentally changed permission of the .ssh folder to 600 and now I am not able to log in to the GCP server through SSH as it's giving me permission denied error.

```
**Connection Failed**
You cannot connect to the VM instance because of an unexpected error. Wait a few moments and then try again.
```

I tried multiple options like, ssh troubleshooting instance, enabling serial console, ssh private key login.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Are you using OSLogin feature? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin

Comment: Also, are you using some 3rd party SSH client, or the SSH button from Cloud Console?

Answer (score 2):

One of the simple ways to fix this would be to use a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux). In this script just execute `chmod 700 /path/to/your/.ssh`.

The startup scripts are executed with root privileges, so it should be able to fix your problem with .ssh folder permissions.

So, what you need to do:

1. Set the startup script.
2. Restart the VM.
3. Wait a minute or two to make sure the script got executed.
4. Remove the startup script from the machine. (no need to restart again)

Comment: Maciek's post is the solution I would use. If you get stuck I wrote an article with more options to repair instances: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all your support, my problem got solved by follwing below document:
[Serial Console with local password using a startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console)